# When I add ng-view to index I receive 404 errors for my templates *FIXED

Tags: angularjs, express, ng-view

**This Problem has been solved.**

**Errors were in the App.js & Server.js**

I'm using Angular on my front-end and I'm using RouteProvider to serve the views to the client. I've added the routing but when I add ng-view into my index page, I receive a 404 errors for my views. With out ng-view I can render my views but not with the Navigation bar across the site like I would like it to be.

What I'm trying to do is have the navigation bar run across the whole site. And render the views within the ng-view under.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE-edge">
        <title>WebApp</title>
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
         <!-- Libraries -->
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.7/angular-route.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/app.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/controllers/navigation.js"></script>

</head>

<body ng-app="webApp>

    <nav ng-controller="NavCtrl">
        <li ng-model="navigation" ng-repeat="navigation in navigation">
        <a href="{{ navigation.link }}">{{navigation.name}}</a>
        </li>
    </nav>

    <div ng-view></div>

</body>
```

**main.html**

```
<h1> Main </h1>
```

**channels.html**

```
<h1> Channels</h1>
```

The same as the above for all the other views!

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module('webApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/index.html',
    controller: 'indexCtrl'
  })
  .when('/main', {
    templateUrl: 'main',
    controller:   'mainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'login',
    controller:   'loginCtrl'
  })
  .when('/channels', {
    templateUrl: 'channels',
    controller:   'channelsCtrl'
  })
  .when('/livenow', {
    templateUrl: 'livenow',
    controller:   'livenowCtrl'
  })
  .when('/signup', {
    templateUrl: 'signup',
    controller:   'signupCtrl'
  })
  .when('/userchannel', {
    templateUrl: 'userchannel',
    controller:   'userchannelCtrl'
  })
  .when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'profile',
    controller:   'profileCtrl'
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: 'index'});
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  });
```

**Navigation.js**

```
    angular.module('webApp').controller('NavCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.navigation = [
        {name: 'main', link: '/main'},
        {name: 'channels', link: '/channels'},
        {name: 'livenow', link: '/livenow'},
        {name: 'login', link: '/login'},
        {name: 'signup', link: '/signup'},
        {name: 'userchannel', link: '/userchannel'},
        {name: 'profile', link: '/profile'}
    ];
}]);
```

**Server.js**

```
    var express = require('express'),
    app = express(),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    mongoose   = require('mongoose');

app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/client/js'));
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/wwww/templates/');
});
app.get('/main', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/www/templates/main.html');
});
app.get('/index', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/www/templates/index.html');
});
app.get('/login', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/www/templates/login.html');
});
app.get('/signup', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/www/templates/signup.html');
});
app.get('/userchannel', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/www/templates/userchannel.html');
});
app.get('/profile', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/www/templates/profile.html');
});
app.get('/livenow', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/www/templates/livenow.html');
});
app.get('/channels', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/www/templates/channels.html');
});

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
  extended: true
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.listen(3000, function() {
    console.log('I\'m Listening...');
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't ng-app be on the body element?

Comment: Moved ng-app to the body tag but still doesn't getting a 404 error when using ng-view in the body.

Comment: it looks like your templates are in the `www/templates/` directory.

Answer (score 0):

**App.js**

```
var app = angular.module('webApp', ['ngResource', 'ngRoute']);

app.config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $routeProvider
  .when('/', {
    templateUrl: 'views/index.html',
    controller: 'indexCtrl'
  })
  .when('/main', {
    templateUrl: 'main',
    controller:   'mainCtrl'
  })
  .when('/login', {
    templateUrl: 'login',
    controller:   'loginCtrl'
  })
  .when('/channels', {
    templateUrl: 'channels',
    controller:   'channelsCtrl'
  })
  .when('/livenow', {
    templateUrl: 'livenow',
    controller:   'livenowCtrl'
  })
  .when('/signup', {
    templateUrl: 'signup',
    controller:   'signupCtrl'
  })
  .when('/userchannel', {
    templateUrl: 'userchannel',
    controller:   'userchannelCtrl'
  })
  .when('/profile', {
    templateUrl: 'profile',
    controller:   'profileCtrl'
  });

  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);


  $routeProvider.otherwise({redirectTo: 'index'});
  // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
  });
```

**Server.js**

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/wwww/templates/');
});
app.get('/main', function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/client/www/templates/main.html');
});
```